# Open gnome-terminal from shell script and hold window open

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to write a script that sets up my programming environment by taking as an argument the name of the project(directory) I want to open

so for example:  **./my_script.sh sample_app**

And here is the script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

wmctrl -s 0
sublime &
sleep 2

wmctrl -s 1
google-chrome &
sleep 2

wmctrl -s 2
Dir="$echo /home/biTNumb/Projects/ruby/workspace/$1"
echo $Dir
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Guard -e ls &
#gnome-terminal -e cd /home/biTNumb/Projects/ruby/workspace/$1 && bundle exec guard &
#gnome-terminal -e cd /home/biTNumb/Projects/ruby/workspace/$1 && rails s &
```

The problem arises when the script executes:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Guard -e ls &
```

I get the message `The child process exited normally with status 0.`:

[image: The child process exited normally with status 0.]

I can't use the terminal after (I can only close it) and the message hides some part of the output. And yet, I have already created a profile and set the *When command exits* dropdown menu to *'Hold the terminal open'*...

**  *I left the comments in the script so you can get the idea of what I'm trying to do*

Comment: Unrelated to the main problem but this `Dir="$echo /home/biTNumb/Projects/ruby/workspace/$1"` is not at all correct though isn't hurting you because the `$echo` variable has no value. If it did then `$Dir` would be set incorrectly. Remove `$echo ` from that assignment. Also quote `"$Dir"` when you use it.

Comment: What do you want that execution of `ls` to do? Show you the output from `ls` and leave a dead window? And you set that setting in the `Guard` profile?

Comment: @EtanReisner I observed that without using "echo" I can't use the special character "*" with a name as a shortcut

Comment: The `$echo` in that string is doing *nothing*. The `echo` command is causing the shell to expand a glob in the unquoted `$Dir` variable. But that's actively bad (in general). Try `printf '[%s]\n' "$Dir"` with the `$echo ` there and see what I mean (compare to `printf '[%s]\n' $Dir` to see what not quoting does).

Comment: @EtanReisner I need the script to open a new terminal run ls in it and then keep it open and ready to use!!I saw what you meant with '$echo'

Comment: If you want the initially spawned window to be usable then you need gnome-terminal to launch a shell and not something like `ls`. What do you get if you don't use the `-e` argument at all? If you want the window available for new tabs that's a different story and I don't know if/how you would do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To execute multiple commands in the same *gnome-terminal* window, use semicolons `;` as separators like below:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "command 1; command 2; ...; bash;"
```

The last command `bash` starts the command-line interpreter so that the terminal doesn't exit at the end (use `$shell` instead of `bash` for a more general solution).

This way you won't need to define a profile with the option *Hold the terminal open* when command exits and you won't get the message `The child process exited with status 0` (which hide some parts of the output).

Here is what you might write (I use backslashes `\` to split lines):

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c \
" ls ;\
cd /home/biTNumb/Projects/ruby/workspace/$1 && bundle exec guard ;\
cd /home/biTNumb/Projects/ruby/workspace/$1 && rails s;\
$bash;"
```